# Where can I find decent visio templates/diagrams for software architecture?

Tags: templates, visio

Anyone have any good urls for templates or diagram examples in Visio 2007 to be used in software architecture?

Comment: just as a note, visio standard edition does not contains by default UML or software diagrams. Its available at Visio Professional or superior.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html) to a Visio Stencil and Template for UML 2.0.

Answer (score 15):

For SOA system architecture, I use the [SOACP](https://www.arcitura.com/notation/) Visio stencil. It provides the symbols that are used in Thomas Erl's SOA book series.

I use the Visio Network and Database stencils to model most other requirements.

Comment: link redirects, so now dead.

Comment: @muttonUp - thanks for the heads up, I've modified the answer to point to the new link.

Answer (score 5):

Beautiful set of stencils from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35772).

Answer (score 2):

There should be templates already included in Visio 2007 for software architecture but you might want to check out [Visio 2007 templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT102115841033.aspx).